# how to display something on a new screen when using react js website

Tags: reactjs

right now my code displays the top 10 states list under the countries info, how do i make it so that the the list of states pop up on a new page? I have tried a few different ways but keep getting errors when linking it to a states.js page. Any help would be much appreciated. I guess my real question is how do i pass the info that I am already getting and just have it display on a new page.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/info?returns=currency,unicodeFlag,dialCode")
      .then((response) => {
        setCountries(response.data.data.slice(0, 10));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleCountryClick = (country) => {
    setSelectedCountry(country);
    setSelectedCountryStates([]);
  };

  const handleFlagClick = () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/states?country=${selectedCountry.name}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const countryData = response.data.data.find((country) => country.name === selectedCountry.name);
        setSelectedCountryStates(countryData.states.slice(0, 10));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Top 10 countries with their flags</h1>
      <ul>
        {countries.map((country) => (
          <li key={country.name}>
            <button onClick={() => handleCountryClick(country)}>
              {country.name}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {selectedCountry && (
        <div>
          <h2>{selectedCountry.name}</h2>
          <img
            src={selectedCountry.unicodeFlag}
            alt={selectedCountry.name}
            onClick={handleFlagClick}
          />
          <p>Currency: {selectedCountry.currency}</p>
          <p>Dial code: {selectedCountry.dialCode}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {selectedCountryStates.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h3>Top 10 states of {selectedCountry.name}</h3>
          <ul>
            {selectedCountryStates.map((state) => (
              <li key={state.name}>{state.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```